# Java HttpRequest get underlying socket?

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

I would like to somehow get the socket that is used for an http request/response. Ultimately goal is to create a

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

which Im guessing can be accomplished by closing the socket in client side code. Is there a way to do so?

EDIT:

As per comments - I have a client emulator that is used in some integration tests. Some test cases require server to throw exceptions, namely

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

as of right now. I understand that *exactly* how sockets are created and used is very much implementation specific and the whole point behind using an http client is to abstract away from that. I would rather not use something like Whitebox.getInternalState() on a http client or request to get the underlying socket out, and would rather not have to implement a way to send a request as text through a socket.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This looks like the XY problem. Please provide more info about what the use case or functionality you're trying to solve, then we can work on that basis. By the way, retrieving the internal socket is implementation specific, too much, I would say, so much that it can change between application server versions, so this approach is not recommended.

Comment: So if you understand that you don't want to do it, why does your title and your question ask how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to provoke that error has nothing to do with obtaining the underlying socket, which in any case is not possible. It is to execute a GET request for a very large resource and never read the response body: just close the input stream immediately and disconnect the `HttpURLConnection.`

Comment: actually I have tried this approach and it results in ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. However I would like to cause specifically an IOException.

Comment: No. Your objective is to produce a connection reset. How that manifests itself in the platform is an irrelevant detail of the implementation. You're not testing the platforms's mapping of TCP conditions to Java exceptions: you're testing the TCP conditions themselves. Or you should be.